# Saving Changes Made in Laravel Voyager to Project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am experimenting with Laravel Voyager for use in an upcoming project. I love how I can make and modify database tables and models using a GUI as opposed to coding it myself. It definitely is a time saver. However, I noticed that Voyager does not generate migration files when you create or modify tables in the control panel. Additionally, I noticed that the changes I made in the control panel are not persisted. When I restart the Dev server or move to production, the changes I made previously on the control panel are gone.

Is there any way I can persist these changes or generate the migration files for use in my production server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your damn right, Voyager doesn't create migrations and its embarrassing comparing to other great features it serves.

I hope its going to change next patch. anyways i'm starting make a hook (plugin) for that.

Right now simply suggest you export your database structure and import it on your production server.

good luck